# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and uri serialization

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, uri

I'm having trouble with implementing "choose save directory" (for all files) feature in my app (in android 5+). What I need is a directory picker - so I decided to use the system one - with sending intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. What have I done already is to implement all the stuff connected with handling the uri later on, while saving file (creating DocumentFile, creating appropriate Stream, even getting a proper path to be used later). What I cannot achieve is saving the URI I receive (for example in SharedPreferences) to make it more permanent, as it makes one of the app settings, that user has to set once.

This is how I tried to save and restore my uri:

```
private Uri getSaveTreeUri() {
    if (mSaveTreeUri == null) {
        String uriString = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(SAVE_TREE_URI, null);
        if (uriString != null) mSaveTreeUri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    }
    return mSaveTreeUri;
}

private void setSaveTreeUri(Uri saveTreeUri) {
    mSaveTreeUri = saveTreeUri;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    editor.putString(SAVE_TREE_URI, saveTreeUri.toString()).commit();
}
```

And then when I use it, by

```
DocumentFile documentFileDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, getSaveTreeUri());
```

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: /tree/D428-E753:Music
```

Is there any possibility to make this work? Thanks a lot for all help!

Answer (score 4):

ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE returns a tree Uri that has associated permissions. The permissions must be persisted if in a later session you want to revisit the Uri.

Use [takePersistableUriPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)) to persist the permissions.

Use [getPersistedUriPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getPersistedUriPermissions()) to get a list of persisted Uris.

Answer (score 2):

As in Peters answer, you must ask the system to take a persistable permission on the URI. First, add the `FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` flag to your intent:

```
folderButton?.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DIR)
}
```

Then you can persist that permission for future uses - the system does the persisting for you:

```
fun saveDirectory(uri: Uri?) {
    if (uri == null) {
        return
    }
    val existing = loadSavedDirectory()
    if (existing != null) {
        // Release existing directory when new one is granted
        contentResolver.releasePersistableUriPermission(existing, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }
    contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
}

fun loadSavedDirectory() : Uri? {
    return contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions?.firstOrNull()?.uri
}
```

This example only handles a single URI - you can hold permissions on multiple URIs.

Comment: Is adding the `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION` flag to the activity intent, also needed/relevant?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to save treeUri in sharedPreference. Answer is late but it might help someone else.

```
//get treeUri from SAF onActicityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
//  Uri treeUri= intent.getData();

private Uri setSaveTreeUri(Uri treeUri) {
    SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString("treeUri", treeUri.toString()).apply();
}
```

Later retrieve treeUri from sharedPreferences, `getSaveTreeUri()` will return treeUri then create `DocumentFile` for accessing folder on external SD storage.

```
private Uri getSaveTreeUri() {
    SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Uri mSaveTreeUri = Uri.parse(mPrefs.getString("treeUri", ""));
    return mSaveTreeUri;
}
```